# How to print all the decimal numbers up to the required last digit in C?

Tags: c, decimal

I need to print the whole answer in decimal form if the exponent was a negative number. but the `float` only has 6 decimal places. because if the answer exceeds 6 decimal places the result would only be `0.000000`. should I use another data type or what?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float power(int base, int exponent);

int main() {
    int base, exponent;
    float result;

    printf("Enter a base number: "); scanf("%d", &base);
    printf("Enter an exponent: "); scanf("%d", &exponent);
    
    result = power(base, exponent);
    printf("Power of %d^%d = %f", base, exponent, result);
    return 0;
}

float power(int base, int exponent) {
    float result = 1;
    while (exponent < 0) {
        {
            result = result / base;
            exponent++;
        }
    }
    while (exponent != 0) {
        result = result * base;
        exponent--;
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You may try `%.10f` or `%g`

Comment: It might matter how large `float` is on your system and what representation it uses.

Comment: As a general rule: use `double` for floating-point variables / values.

Comment: Thanks for everyone who replied and helped me!! I appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Print specifier**

As `float` is a *floating* point number (significand and exponent), use `"%e"` or `"%g"` to display the number in exponential notation rather than the fixed notation of `"%f"`.

```
printf("%e\n", result);  // exponential
printf("%g\n", result);  // exponential for large and tiny values
printf("%a\n", result);  // exponential, but with a hexadecimal significand.
```

To print more than the default of 6 significant decimal digits, use the optional *precision*:

```
printf("%.8e\n", result);  // 1 + 8 significant decimal places.
```

As `float` stores a value internally with a binary significant and OP likely wants a decimal output, it is neither wise to print too few nor informative to print too many significant decimal places.  For `float`, consider using `FLT_DECIMAL_DIG` (typically 9) to guide the printed decimal precision.

```
#include <float.h>
printf("%.*e\n", FLT_DECIMAL_DIG-1, result);
// or
printf("%.*g\n", FLT_DECIMAL_DIG, result);
```

---

**Type**

As [@pmg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66598538/how-to-print-all-the-decimal-numbers-up-to-the-required-last-digit-in-c/66599141#comment117730561_66598538) suggests, consider `double` instead of `float` in C.  It is the default floating point type and has 53 binary digits of precision (~17 decimal or so).

---

**Notes**

Code like `result/base` (`float/int`) and `result*base1` can incur a small amount of round-off error on each iterations.   With higher `exponent`, more potentially error.

To "print **all** the decimal numbers up to the required last digit" can get into  some [heavy details](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/212490/29485).

**Exponentiation by squaring**

Rather than looping, consider [Exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring): faster and more accurate.

```
double pow_f(int ibase, int exponent) {
  unsigned expo = exponent < 0 ? 0u - exponent : exponent;
  double base = ibase;
  double pow = 1.0;
  while (expo > 0) {
    if (expo % 2) {
      pow *= base;
    }
    base *= base;
    expo /= 2;
  }
  if (ibase < 0) {
    pow = 1.0/pow;
  }
  return pow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: "%.***N***f", where ***N*** is the number of digits after point you want.

--- BUT ---

Long answer:

1. the number of significant (i.e. useful) digits after point depends on the representation of "float" on your machine AND on the magnitude of the value. On most systems the "float" type is IEEE 754 single-precision, wich has 23 bits of mantissa. This roughly corresponds to 7 decimal digits, including the ones BEFORE the decimal point. If the number is big enough, none of the digits after the point is meaningful.
2. Due to the base-2 representation, most values whose representation in base-10 has a finite number of non-zero digits can't be expressed exactly.

Comment: IEEE-754 single-precision has 24 bits in the significand. (Mantissa is an old term for the fraction portion of a logarithm. The fraction portion of a floating-point number is the significand.) 23 bits are encoded in the primary significand field. 1 bit is encoded via the exponent field.

Comment: Yes, 24 bits of significand, but including an implicit "1" at head position. In IEEE-754 it is omitted since it doesn't bring information. So there are 2^23 possible values for franction portion.

Comment: Please do not confuse the mathematical value of a floating-point number with its encoding. Per Table 3.2 in IEEE 754-2008, the significand of a binary “single” has 24 bits. It is not omitted. The floating-point number acts in operations exactly as if it includes all 24 bits. This question asks about printing the values of floating-point numbers, so the mathematical value is relevant. This question does not involve storing or encoding floating-point numbers, so the encoding is irrelevant. Although the leading bit is sometimes called “implicit,” it is in fact encoded by the exponent field.